# Skip to next modified file in git diff?

Tags: git

I made the mistake of upgrading a Visual Studio project from 2008 to 2010 without checking in my previous changes first.  Because of this I have a huge system generated file (10k+ lines) that had every 4th line changed.

I'm usually pretty good about checking in stuff often, so I will typically just use the down key to scroll through my changes.  In this case it will take several lifetimes to scroll through the changes to the system generated file.

Is there a way to skip to the next modified file after you have done a `git diff` so that you don't have to scroll through every change on every file?

Comment: you can just use `git diff fileName` if you have a small change set.

Comment: I'd like to see all files that have been modified, just skip the giant one...

Answer (score 117, accepted):

By default, `git diff` pipes its output through `less`. So you can use the `less` commands to search for the next header. Type `/^diff` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to skip to the next file.

Comment: Do I need to exit my current diff first?  I tried doing it from inside my current diff and it said `Pattern not found`

Comment: The `/` command searches from the current position you're looking at. So if you get that message, then there are no further lines that start with `diff` in the output.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like what you *really* want to do is to split these (uncommitted) changes into two separate commits. Do a `git add large.file.name` and then `git commit`, then all the changes left over will be the other files that *aren't* the large one.

Comment: Then after that, use `n` to get to the next occurrence of `^diff`, and `N` for the previous one. This should work until use another search pattern with `/`.

Answer (score 20):

While in `git diff`, simply hit <kbd>n</kbd> to go straight to the next file, and again to the one afterwards, and so on.

You can also use <kbd>N</kbd> to go back a file.

(For these commands to work, you'll need to first type `/^diff` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464561/738675).)

Comment: Pressing `n` finds the next search term. You need to search for a common part of the file header for this to work.

Answer (score 8):

For other useful commands type `h` for help (while being in `git diff`, which is being in `less`).

In particular:

```
                           JUMPING

  g  <  ESC-<       *  Go to first line in file (or line N).
  G  >  ESC->       *  Go to last line in file (or line N).
  p  %              *  Go to beginning of file (or N percent into file).
  t                 *  Go to the (N-th) next tag.
  T                 *  Go to the (N-th) previous tag.
  {  (  [           *  Find close bracket } ) ].
  }  )  ]           *  Find open bracket { ( [.
  ESC-^F <c1> <c2>  *  Find close bracket <c2>.
  ESC-^B <c1> <c2>  *  Find open bracket <c1>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you to use [`tig`](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/). It's a curses interface for `git`, and a very good one.

With `tig status` you can see the index status, and by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on any of the files, you see it's diff. <kbd>h</kbd> shows you the help menu, but it's a vi-shortcuts-based interface.

I think in any debian-based distro you can just `apt-get install` it, or you can make it from the linked site.

Comment: By default `tig` would not allow you to quickly jump between files, but you can do it with the following binding: `bind diff F :/^\+\+\+`

Comment: @VitalyB thanks for that - I'm surprised there isn't a default binding for it. For future SOers, with the above `shift+f` will search for the next file. Since it's not a search, then `n` will move to the next file and `shift+n` will move to the previous file.

Comment: meant to say "since it's _now_ a search"

also, `bind diff` stopped working for me. Not sure why, but this works: `bind stage F :/^\+\+\+`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to call [`update-index`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) command and tell it to pretend that one giant file didn't change. There's a more complete example [here](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
:n                *  Examine the (N-th) next file from the command line.
```

See this in the help for `less`.

```
                      CHANGING FILES
:e [file]            Examine a new file.
^X^V                 Same as :e.
:n                *  Examine the (N-th) next file from the command line.
:p                *  Examine the (N-th) previous file from the command line.
:x                *  Examine the first (or N-th) file from the command line.
:d                   Delete the current file from the command line list.
=  ^G  :f            Print current file name.
```

Comment: That only works if `less` is dealing with multiple files. Here it is just paging the output and has no concept of files.